# Storing new bearings for the next 5 years. Will they last?

Tags: bearing, storage

I live in a region where everything is on the rise and something which is available today, may or may not be available tomorrow (or may be available at a much higher price) and it might be very rare and hard to find which is annoying. Therefore, I was thinking about buying some necessary spare parts for my car NOW and store them for the next 4 - 5 years. Bearings are important for me such as idler and tensioner bearings for both timing belt and serpentine belt systems. Since there is grease inside the bearings, do you think they will fail if I buy them now and store them on the shelf at room temperature for 5 years? Will they be usable for my next service?

Comment: It's your decision what to do, but consider the possibility that your car won't survive 4-5 years for other reasons - e.g. being written off in an accident, or a major breakdown where it is not economic to repair an old car (e.g. a replacement engine)

Comment: @alephzero - A breakdown or accident can happen at any time during a car's lifetime. My experience taught me to always have important spare parts in advance. It is not a matter of how long your car lasts, it is a matter of availability of parts. I always had problem to buy parts for routine services of my car due to price and availability. Therefore, the sooner I buy, I not only pay less but also I find OEM parts instead of cheap and fake Chinese parts which threaten the health of my engine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they come in the original packaging then they should be fine. New bearings come in boxes, with a plastic or oiled paper wrapping protecting the bearing - even some with granules to absorb moisture.

If they come loose then no. So you will need to give them the protection they need.

Seen bearings and other items taken out of storage and they look like they were made yesterday 10 years ago...

Make sure you store them in a place suitable ie it won't get flooded etc

Comment: The bearings I bought recently for my belt service, were in a package (cardboard) box and wrapped in paper. So, according to your answer, I can buy another set of those bearing for long term storage. To protect them against moisture, I can put the original packaging inside another sealed box.